# Laravel Sanctum check if user has tokens

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum, laravel-api

I'm trying to log in the user and If this user has any token in the personal_access_tokens table remove them and create a new one. I tried it, but this throws me an error saying `Call to a member function currentAccessToken() on null`

Here is my code I used in my login method,

```
$request->validate([
    'email'    => 'required | email',
    'password' => 'required'
]);


$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

if (!$user){
    return response(['payback' => 'Account not found']);
} else if(!Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)){
    return response(['payback' => 'Incorrect Credentials']);
}

if($request->user()->currentAccessToken()){
    $request->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();
} else {
    return response(['payback' => 'Not Has Tokens']);
}

$token = $user->createToken('ribluma_access_token')->plainTextToken;
```

I tried a solution that works,

```
        $request->validate([
            'email'    => 'required | email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);


        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        if (!$user) {
            return response(['payback' => 'Account not found']);
        } else if (!Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            return response(['payback' => 'Incorrect Credentials']);
        }

        if (count(DB::table('personal_access_tokens')->where('tokenable_id', $user->id)->get()) > 0) {
            DB::table('personal_access_tokens')->where('tokenable_id', $user->id)->delete();
        }

        $token = $user->createToken('ribluma_access_token')->plainTextToken;
        $response = [
            'user'  => $user,
            'token' => $token
        ];

        return $response;
```

This is the exact thing I want to do. But there should be a better way I guess. Really appreciate it if somebody could help thanks.

Comment: use $user variable here $user->currentAccessToken()

Comment: @BhargavRangani I used like this if($user->currentAccessToken()){
            return response(['payback' => 'Has Tokens']);
        } , but not working

Answer (score 2):

```
    if(auth('sanctum')->check()){
        auth()->user()->tokens()->delete();
    }

    $token = $user->createToken('ribluma_access_token')->plainTextToken;
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this code for login**

```
$request->validate([
    'email'    => 'required | email',
    'password' => 'required'
]);


$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

if (!$user || !Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
     return response(
        'message' => ['These credentials do not match our records.']
    ,404);
}

if(auth('sanctum')->check()){
    auth()->user()->tokens()->delete();
}

$token = $user->createToken('ribluma_access_token')->plainTextToken;
```

**Update of Laravel >= 7:**

```
// Revoke the token that was used to authenticate the current request...
$request->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();

// Revoke a specific token...
$user->tokens()->where('id', $tokenId)->delete();
```

Comment: undefined method tokens()

Comment: try auth()->logout();